# Grails 3.0.0.M1 - GGTS and Netbeans can not import project with the gradle extension

Tags: grails, netbeans, netbeans-8, ggts, grails-3.0

I've just tried to import a Grails 3.0.0.M1 test project in GGTS 3.6.3 after installing the gradle integration extension. It fails.

Do I need more extensions installed?

Thank you!

The error:

```
Download http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         :test:unspecified > org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.M1
      > Could not parse POM http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
         > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.2.1.RELEASE.
            > Could not parse POM http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.2.1.RELEASE.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
            > Could not parse POM http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.2.1.RELEASE.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
      > Could not parse POM http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
         > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.2.1.RELEASE.
            > Could not parse POM http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.2.1.RELEASE.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
            > Could not parse POM http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom
               > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.2.1.RELEASE.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.
                  > Failed to create SHA1 hash for file /home/rawi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/205ff23f67b19c94ced78801eefe2ea861a2c2e8/spring-boot-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 12.278 secs
```

UPDATE:
Neither Netbeans 8.0.2 can it, because an error in gradle script:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE.
Required by:
    :test:unspecified > org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.M1
```